# How to solve this error No route found for "GET /etat/delete_emp_nbre_administrative/101": Method Not Allowed (Allow: DELETE)?

Tags: html, forms, twig, symfony5

I add a function in my controller with a route annotation and `methods="DELETE"`.

When I create a form in Twig with a delete button, I get this error

> No route found for "GET /etat/delete_emp_nbre_administrative/101": Method Not Allowed (Allow: DELETE)

In template

```html
<form action="{{path('delete_emp_nbre_administrative', {'id' : NbreAdministrative.id })}}">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
  <button class="btn btn-danger" >supprimer</button>
</form>
```

In controller

```php
/**
 * @Route("/etat/delete_emp_nbre_administrative/{id}", name="delete_emp_nbre_administrative", methods="DELETE")
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you defined your route will only accept access via the `DELETE` method of HTTP.
In HTML, you can only use `POST` and `GET` methods, also sometimes called HTTP verbs.

And since you didn't define any `method="..."` in your `form`, the default is `GET`.

> The **`method`** and **`formmethod`** content attributes are enumerated attributes with the following keywords and states:
>
> - The keyword **`get`**, mapping to the state **GET**, indicating the HTTP GET method.
> - The keyword **`post`**, mapping to the state **POST**, indicating the HTTP POST method.
> - The keyword **`dialog`**, mapping to the state **dialog**, indicating that submitting the [`<form>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#elementdef-form) is intended to close the `dialog` box in which the form finds itself, if any, and otherwise not submit.
>
> The *invalid value default* for these attributes is the [GET](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#http-get) state. The *missing value default* for the [`method`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-method) attribute is also the [GET](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#http-get) state. (There is no missing value default for the [`formmethod`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-submitbuttonelements-formmethod) attribute.)
>
> The **method** of an element is one of those states. If the element is a [`Submit Button`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-statedef-input-submit) and has a [`formmethod`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-submitbuttonelements-formmethod) attribute, then the element’s [method](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#forms-method) is that attribute’s state; otherwise, it is the [form owner](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#form-owner)’s [`method`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-method) attribute’s state.

<sup>*Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-method*</sup>

So you fix is just to remove the `methods` attribute of your annotation:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/etat/delete_emp_nbre_administrative/{id}", name="delete_emp_nbre_administrative")
 */
```

---

Note that the `DELETE` method or verb, along with `PUT` and `PATCH` are used when you are making RESTful services.

Comment: Thank you very much that work. There are a security problem when i remove the methods attribute       ( DELETE ) of annotation ?

Comment: Well, no because it is not meant for HTML, so you cannot even use it at all in an HTML form. This said you might want to consider using post rather than GET and [CSRF tokens](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/csrf.html) there. But that would make it a totally different question.

Comment: If this answer helped you, please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).